# How do I troubleshoot unit tests using xdebug?

Tags: 8, testing

I have xdebug in a Vagrant box, based on VDD, set up and working correctly. Breakpoints trigger phpstorm and mostly works just fine. But when I enable the testing module and try to run a single test on `admin/config/development/testing`  where a breakpoint in the test source code has been setup, nothing gets triggered. I am assuming that's because PHPUnit is using a separate process. I [went though this](https://www.drupal.org/node/30011) but it's not helping much.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to figure out why the debugger would not **initially** trigger for tests while it's triggered for other normal requests. Then I changed the `xdebug.remote_autostart = 0` to `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` and it started working. I even changed it back to `xdebug.remote_autostart = 0` and it kept working.

I also found out that one can also temporarily enable the phpstorm `break at first line` by xdebug settings:

[image]
I presume there is not one answer fit all but hope this helps others.